# Is it better to have an add/remove feature or a "manage list" function?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation

I have a data table and currently the only thing you can do is add/remove things from this list. So I have it setup where you click "add" and it shows you the master list of all items you can add. These items can only be added to one per group i.e. item A cannot belong to any other group if it is in group 1 already. You can also select the items using a checkbox and "remove" them from the list. Since I have the master list, where all used items will still appear but look disabled, should I remove both buttons and just use a "manage list" button where users can select/deselect items at their own convenience? Or should I still separate the two functions?

Comment: Do you have any screenshots you can share? I think it might depend on how you're showing the master list and the groups that items are assigned to.